# How to make the visibility of a component of inner class to gone in customized listview

Tags: android

I am using a customized listview in android.In my customized listview class Voucherlistcustomization1 i have a linearlayout named linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1.On the onclick of another layout in layout voucher in outer class Voucher i need to make  layout linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1 visibilty to gone.However i am not getting access to the layout in outer class.

```
    public class Voucher extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnItemClickListener
    {

        ListView listviewvoucher;
        private Voucherlistcustomization1 vouchertextadapter=null;
        public ArrayList<String>Addelemntstovoucher = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.voucher);

            Addelemntstovoucher.add("SHOPPER STOP");
            Addelemntstovoucher.add("Expire date:5-8-2012");

            if(vouchertextadapter == null)
            {
                vouchertextadapter=new Voucherlistcustomization1(this,0, Addelemntstovoucher);

            }   

            listviewvoucher.setAdapter(vouchertextadapter);


            Log.d("customerfaname",""+Addelemntstovoucher);


            listviewvoucher.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,long id) 
                {
                    Log.d("Clicked","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"+a);

                }
            }); 
        }   

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
        if(v==linearlayout_Voucher_to_Grab){
                linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1.setVisibility(View.GONE) ;
        }

        }

        public class Voucherlistcustomization1 extends ArrayAdapter<String>
        {
            LinearLayout linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1;

            public Voucherlistcustomization1(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<String> objects) 
            {

                super(context, textViewResourceId,objects);

            }


            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {
                if(convertView == null) 
                {
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customized_listview_for_voucher, null);                
                }


                linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1);

                          //components present in the  customized_listview_for_voucher layout
                String text1 = getItem(position);
                TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                textView1.setText(text1);

                String text2 = getItem(position);
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                textView2.setText(text2);

                String text3 = getItem(position);
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                textView3.setText(text3);


                return convertView;
            }    

        }

    }

My issue here is that on the Onclick of :
    (v==linearlayout_Voucher_to_Grab)   
    {
            linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1.setVisibility(View.GONE) ;
    }



I am trying to make the layout  linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1.setVisibility(View.GONE) ; visibity to gone however the layout(linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1) is a component in the class Voucherlistcustomization1 in the Inner class Voucherlistcustomization1.Can someone please tell me how do i set the visibity of that layout to false.
```

Comment: Why an inner class?  Why not just a public (or package private) class?

Comment: I wanted to add the code in one class itself for that activity

Comment: OK, but personally absent a good reason, I think you're design would be better using a standalone class.  More reusable too.  Then there is no messing around with handlers, runnables, runOnUiThread etc and, you can use it in your layout XML like any other listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

runOnUIThread(new Runnable {
       public void run() {
               layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
})

The problem may be that you work with the View not in the original thread and that will be the solution

Comment: SVS i basically want to get access to the components(linearlayout called as linearlayoutearnloyaltypoints1) defined in the innerclass(customized row for list view called as Voucherlistcustomization1)in theouter class.